# Does "She struggled to get a job" mean she did not get a job?

Tags: meaning

Does "She struggled to get a job" mean she was not able to get a job or does it mean she got a job but with great difficulty?

Comment: In *some* contexts, such as ***They struggled to survive***, there's no doubt their efforts *were* successful (if not, we'd explicitly say ***They died*** or similar). I can't think of any "opposite" contexts (where there's no doubt the struggle was *unsuccessful*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the guy with asthma who failed to breathe is clearly no more; the one who struggled to do so may still be with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isolated fragment 'she struggled to get a job' does not, by itself, tell you anything about whether she eventually got one, or not. That information might come from context, or further words:

She struggled to get a job, and after six months decided to go to college instead.

She struggled to get a job, but after six months obtained a post in a office.